# Rails 3 - WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I have a has_many through relationship between Course and User.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :enrollments, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :users, :through => :enrollments

  attr_accessible :description, :duration, :name, :prerequisites, :short_name, :start_date, :user_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :users_attributes
```

and User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :subjects, :class_name => "Course"  # to get this call user.subjects
has_many :enrollments, :dependent => :delete_all
has_many :courses, :through => :enrollments
```

and Enrollment:

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :course
belongs_to :user

attr_accessible :course_id, :user_id

end
```

Now I'm trying to set user_ids from inside Course, using a nested form. It keeps giving me that Mass Assignment warning, and nothing is saved. I read I was supposed to add attr_accessible user_id but it still doesn't work.

Even if I do something like this from the rails console:

```
@c.update_attributes({:user_ids => [7,8]})
```

with @c being the course

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `user_ids`, not `user_id`.

You need to add `user_ids` to your `attr_accessible`.

Comment: Oh God, I can't believe how blind I was! THANK YOU!